# Releasing device memory mapped to user space if program terminates

Tags: windows

I am very new to Windows. I want to access device memory from user space and after doing some googling, kind of got an understanding on how to do this.

1. MmMapIoSpaceEx  to map the physical address to system VA
2. IoAllocateMdl to allocate MDL for the same VA.
3. MmBuildMdlForNonPagedPool to update the MDL with underlying physical addresses.
4. MmMapLockedPagesSpecifyCache with UserMode flag.

My question is after mapping this memory to userspace, if program crashes for some reason, do I need to unmap using MmUnmapLockedpages.

I was thinking since the page table for the process will get destroyed as part of it's exit, unmapping might not be required. In that case I need to call only IoFreeMdl.

Is my understanding Right?. It would be great if you could point to any resources.

I really appreciate your help.